# Time measurement repeatedly makes mistake in specific places

Tags: c++, time

I need to write program which would measure performance of certain data structures. But I can't get reliable result. For example when I measured performance 8 times for the **same** size of structure, every other result was different(for example: 15ms, 9ms, 15ms, 9ms, 15ms, ...), although the measurements weren't dependent on each other(for every measurement I generated new data). I tried to extract the problem and here is what I have:

```
while (true) {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
        ;
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << duration<double, milli>(end - start).count() << " ";
    _getch();
}
```

What happens when I run this code is - In the first run of loop the time is significantly higher than in next runs. Well it's always higher in the first run, but from time to time also in other measurements.

Example output: 0.006842 0.002566 0.002566 0.002138 0.002993 0.002138 0.002139 ...

And that's the behaviour **everytime** I start the program.

Here are some things I tried:

- It **does** matter if I compile Release or Debug version. Measurements are still faulty but in different places.
- I turned off code optimization.
- I tried using different clocks.
- And what I think is quite important - While my *Add* function wasn't empty, the problem depended on data size. For example program worked well for most data sizes but let's say for element count of 7500 measurements were drastically different.
- I just deleted part of code **after** the segment i posted here. And guess what, first measurement is no longer faulty. I have no idea what's happening here.

I would be glad if someone explained to me what can be possible cause of all of this.

Comment: Ah, right sorry, i forgot to delete this line when I tried to simplify the problem, thanks.

Comment: http://quick-bench.com/ might help to compare code.

Comment: Your j-loop can entirely be optimized out.

Comment: @Jarod42 I turned off optimization in project settings.

Comment: Benchmark non optimized code is not really useful.

Comment: Eventually I will turn it on, but I turned it off now so I can be sure what is measured.

Comment: @Jarod42 The use here is ensuring that the compiler isn't doing any dirty tricks like a 2:1 unrolling of the outer loop (which could likewise cause the alternating times), not to mention optimizing out the inner loop as you suggested. Not useful for determining real-world performance, of course, but this is closer to meta-profiling anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that code, it's likely that you're just seeing the effect of the instruction cache or the micro-op cache. The first time the test is run, more instructions have to be fetched and decoded; on subsequent runs the results of that are available in the caches. As for the alternating times you were setting on some other code, that could be fluctuations in the branch prediction buffer, or something else entirely.

There's too many complex processes involved in execution on modern CPUs to expect a normal sequence of instructions to execute in a fixed amount of time. While it's possible to measure or at least account for these externalities when looking at individual instructions, for nontrivial code you basically have to accept empirical measurements including their variance.

Comment: Well, the positive part is that probably it isn't my mistake haha. When I make full measurements for BST, for similiar sizes of structure the difference between measurements can reach even 15-20%. And becouse of that I can't really determine complexity(for project) of the operation looking at graph. Anyways, thanks for the answer, maybe I will try just one more time to write the code differently.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of operating system you're on, for durations this short, the scheduler can cause huge differences. If your thread is preempted, then you have the idle duration in your time. There are also many things that happen that you don't see: caches, pages, allocation. Modern systems are complex.

You're better off making the whole benchmark bigger, and then doing multiple runs on each thing you're testing, and then using something like [ministat from FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ministat) to compare the runs of the same test, and then compare the ministat for the different things you're comparing.

To do this effectively, your benchmark should try to use the same amount of memory as the real workload, so that you memory access is a part of the benchmark.

Comment: Thread preemption would cause variances in the milliseconds, not in the microseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think what I already have will be good enough, but It's good to know there is a better way to do it if I will need to. Also thanks for pointing out the precision problem, it totally slipped my mind.

Comment: It's not precision, it's units. The values being printed are in milliseconds, because that's the representation `duration` was requested to return. And 0.006842 milliseconds is 6.8 microseconds.

Comment: @Sneftel My mistake on units, removed from the answer. And yes, thread preemption would cause milliseconds of variance, but there are other system events (eg. interrupt handling, preempting thread relinquishing its timeslice early) will also cause variance. Holding everything constant is hard, so running multiple times helps.

Comment: @KonradStręk As pointed out, my duration comment was incorrect.